# Is my server expected to return a 200 for an HTTP OPTIONS methods when the connection point is forbidden to the current user?

Tags: rest, http, cors, http-method

Reading various documentations (such as the [w3c CORS](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)), I have to say that the `OPTIONS` does not seem that well documented at all.

I'm wondering whether my REST server is doing it right, which is returning a 403 if the client tries to access a connection point which is forbidden (whether it exists or not does not even always matter, although at times the server may return 404 instead.)

The `OPTIONS` documentation, though, does not seem to infer that such a return code is valid.

I've found [this stackoverflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702962/can-an-http-options-request-return-a-204-or-should-it-always-return-200) where the accepted answer seems to say that we can return any error code.

I would imagine that it would be a security hole to allow the `OPTIONS` to passthrough when the user is not allowed. At the same time, the `OPTIONS` defines the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header and I don't see how I could ever make that header useful if I return a 403 on such connection points. (In other words, to me that sounds contradictory.)

Comment: And actually if I detect a 403 along the way, I can then generate the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: If you do actually want the OPTIONS response to be useful as far as CORS-enabling the server, then you shouldn’t return 403 just because the user isn’t logged in.

**Details:**

It’s never invalid for a server to return a `403` for an `OPTIONS` request. The CORS protocol doesn’t require your server to return a `2xx` success response for an `OPTIONS` request. But if your server *doesn’t* return a `2xx` for `OPTIONS` requests to a particular URL, then CORS preflight `OPTIONS` requests to that URL will fail. So if that’s what you actually *want* to happen, then responding with a `403` is fine — so is responding with a `405` or a `501` or whatever other response code might have a meaning appropriate to your particular case.

But it’s important to keep in mind that the CORS protocol requires browsers to never send authentication credentials as part of the CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request. So if your server is configured to require authentication in order for `OPTIONS` requests to produce `2xx` success responses, then all CORS preflights coming from browsers are going to fail 100% of the time. In other words, you’d be ensuring that all requests will fail that are coming to the server from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser and that add custom response headers (e.g., `Content-Type` or `Authorization` headers) and so that trigger preflights.

I’m not aware of any specific security hole that could occur by responding with `2xx` to unauthenticated `OPTIONS` requests (from users who are not allowed). That doesn’t permit users to get any info from your server beyond whatever you intentionally choose to put into the response headers you send in response to the `OPTIONS` request. And of course it doesn’t prevent you from requiring authentication for `GET` or `POST` or whatever other methods. But in terms of the CORS protocol, it’s the only way for your server to indicate what methods and request headers it allows in requests from frontend JavaScript.

---

Note also: the current actively-maintained requirements for CORS are defined in the Fetch spec https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org. The https://w3.org/TR/cors spec is obsolete and no longer maintained and shouldn’t be used for anything (see https://w3.org/2017/08/16-webappsec-minutes.html#item03 and the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45926657/441757).

I don’t know why the https://w3.org/TR/cors spec isn’t already been clearly marked obsolete, but I’ll try to make sure it gets marked as such soon.

Comment: Yeah, good luck on getting *that* to happen. Last I heard (from @annevk), no-one at W3 can be bothered to mark it as obsolete, so it just sits there. Mind you, I think in some ways the W3 doc is better-written for front-end developers - the Fetch spec is really written for browser developers...